# WCF DataContract deserialization of complex types

Tags: wcf, serialization

I have a service that returns a collection of MyClass objects.
If all of the MyClass instances have null in MyClass2Reference then everything works fine.
Otherwise, I get a "Connection reset" error on the client side.
What am I doing wrong?

```
[DataContract]
public MyClass
{
[DataMember]
int ID;
[DataMember]
MyClass2 MyClass2Reference;
}

[DataContract]
public MyClass2
{
[DataMember]
int ID;
[DataMember]
string Name;
}
```

Comment: Might consider closing this as "too localized?"

Comment: did you every find out what the solution was, if so please udpate your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - it was a problem with [NHibernate lazy proxy objects](http://timvasil.com/blog14/post/2008/02/WCF-serialization-with-NHibernate.aspx).

Comment: How so? Any chance you can elaborate on what solved your problem?

Comment: I gave the link in my answer.

Comment: It's considered good practice on SO to give a brief description also, not least because sooner or later that link will break.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding some tracing to your WCF config and then running the results through Service Trace Viewer as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023.aspx)

would have given a good error description. I've found that is always a good place to start when dealing with strange WCF errors.